# Hide column headers in an XPages viewPanel only when view is collapsed

Tags: xpages, columnheader, viewpanel

I have a simple viewPanel in XPages with a few columns where the first column is categoriezed. When user is entering the view it is collapsed using the expandLevel= "1"

I have now a request to hide the column headers that are not displayed when the view is collapsed, and show them when one or more categories is expanded.

how can I do that?

thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what kind of display / layout you have in mind but I played around with that thought a bit. Just a few ideas, nothing that I really tried (don't have a server at hand right now):

Assuming that you wish to hide *all* column headers when all categories are fully collapsed one way you could go is to use some client side scripting setting an initial `display:none` styling for the data table's `<thead>` element; or if you can't reach thead for whatever reason you might as well address all column headers through their separate styleClass `xspPanelViewColumnHeader`.

Reacting to the the expand / collapse events might be a bit tricky;

Speaking of more control: all in all it might be a much better idea not to go for a view panel at all. You could instead use a `<xp:dataTable>` or even `<xp:repeat>` control which means more work but is giving you much more control over what you can achieve here. Or you even go for something like a b jQuery data table.

Comment: Thanks. I tried a client side script to check if some rows exist but I could not get it to work because of how the view panel is refreshed.